# how to insert variable's value in SQlite Database in Qt cpp

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, sqlite

i am using Qt and i have written c++ code,i have already connected with sqlite database.i want to insert name in database

```
std::string name="Hello";
qry.prepare( "INSERT INTO s_no (Name,Status) VALUES ('name','1' )");
if( !qry.exec() )
    qDebug() << qry.lastError();
else
    qDebug( "Inserted!" );
```

but in db i am finding name only , not hello;

please help me..thank you so much in advance

Comment: qry.prepare( "INSERT INTO s_no (Name,Status) VALUES ('"+name+"','1' )");        i have tried dis also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ and SQL are two different programming languages, and execute in different environments. This means that C++ objects are not visible in SQL.

In theory, it would be possible to construct the string containing the SQL command so that the value of the `name` variable is inserted directly into it:

```
qry.prepare("INSERT INTO s_no (Name,Status) VALUES('" + name + "', '1')");  // don't do this
```

However, this will blow up if the name contains a quote. Escaping quotes would be possible with additional code, but a better way of getting variable values into an SQL query is to use parameters:

```
qry.prepare("INSERT INTO s_no (Name,Status) VALUES(?, '1')");
qry.bindValue(0, name);
```

(This is the only sensible way of using blob values in a query.)

Answer (score -1):

Try making name a QString. You can change std::string to QString by using: `QString name2 = QString::fromStdString(name);`. Don't forget to include: `#include <QString>`.

Comment: Try this: `qry.prepare( "INSERT INTO s_no2 (Name, Status) VALUES (:name, '1')" );
qry.bindValue( ":name", name);`.

Comment: qry.prepare(  "INSERT INTO s_no (serial,status)" "VALUES (?,?)");
         qry.addBindValue(name);
         qry.addBindValue(1);       this worked...  thanks for reply